# Dovecot Aborted login user=<>

Tags: dovecot, vestacp

I have a problem with Dovecot configuration.
I installed full pack VestaCP (Hosting Control Panel), it's included Dovecot.
(Early, i configure many servers with this panel, and everything works ok)

After adding new email address by panel, i trying connecting by Apple Mail and Mozila thunderbird, but mail client shows error about invalid email/password.

In `/var/log/dovecot.log` i finded this:

```
imap-login: Info: Aborted login (auth failed, 2 attempts in 1 secs): user=<>, method=LOGIN, rip=x.x.x.x, lip=y.y.y.y, TLS, session=<zzz>
```

Why "`user=<>`" ? I think there should be an email there, but it's empty? 
In the mail client the login is specified, of course.

If it's help:

- OS Ubuntu 16.04. AWS EC2.
- Ports 143, 587 in AWS Security Groups opened.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this!

In the vesta panel, I go to "User" and make a "Rebuild mail".

After that, in dovecot.log i found new error:

```
Error: User initialization failed: namespace configuration error: Duplicate namespace prefix: ""
imap: Error: Invalid user settings. Refer to server log for more information.
```

Resolve for this problem i found [here](https://forum.vestacp.com/viewtopic.php?t=17154#p72031)

After remove file /etc/dovecot/conf.d/15-mailboxes.conf and restarting service, it works!

Comment: I'm using Vesta as well, after checking the logs at `/var/log/dovecot.log`, I have moved 15-mailboxes.conf to ~ and rebooted the server - Roundcube started working again.